# Why is this simple SVG icon scaling?

Tags: html, css, svg

I have a jsFiddle demonstrating this:
http://jsfiddle.net/L0a3xa7j/1/

I've made a simple SVG icon for a window restore. I wish it to be 13x11. Here's the page markup:

```
<svg display="none" width="0" height="0" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <defs>
    <symbol id="i-restore" viewBox="0 0 13 11">
      <line  x1="2"  y1="0" x2="13" y2="0" stroke-width="1" stroke="white"/>
      <line  x1="13" y1="0" x2="13" y2="9" stroke-width="1" stroke="white"/>
      <rect x="0" y="2" width="11" height="9" stroke="white" fill="none" stroke-width="2"/>
    </symbol>
  </defs>
</svg>

<svg class="svg"><use xlink:href="#i-restore"/></svg>
```

And here's the CSS:

```
body{background:#000}

.svg
{
    color:#FFF; width:13px; height:11px;
}
```

I'm expecting a 1 pixel space between the rectangle and the 2 lines. The rectangle should be 2 pixels thick in stroke and the lines 1 pixel thick. I don't understand why the aspect ratio is not correct when the css pixel dimensions match that of the SVG's viewbox.

What's the correct way to fix this? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1/2 of a stroke occurs inside the boundary of the shape and 1/2 outside

```
<rect x="0" y="2" width="11" height="9" stroke="white" fill="none" stroke-width="2"/>
```

starts at -1, 1 and is 13 pixels wide and 11 pixels high. Your svg size isn't big enough to accommodate the size of its contents and the overflow is clipped.

That's why the spaces between things are not as you expect either.

Answer (score 2):

You're giving the lines a stroke of 2.

Set `stroke-width="1"`. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jnfsmile/50b8dh28/1/)(I enlarged the view)

**EDIT**

Try a square viewBox [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jnfsmile/50b8dh28/2/)

```
viewBox="0 0 15 15"
```

Comment: You are right. I'll put that back. But even in your example there is scaling occurring. The right side of the rectangle for example is thicker than the left and the top is thicker than the bottom. If you don't enlarge the size there is not 1 pixel of space between the lines and rectangle.